# Awaiting query.FindAsync() from Parse doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have an online database from Parse.com. There's a table "Vakantie", that contains 3 objects, so the table data isn't big.

I'm trying to get all the objects from that table so I can display them through my VakantieController in a View.

Parse has an own documentation where sample code is provided. I copied their sample code and edited it so that it fits for my website.

The сode:

VakantieController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vakantiesTask = vakantieRepository.FindAll();
    IEnumerable<Vakantie> vakanties = vakantiesTask.Result;
    return View(vakanties);
}
```

VakantieRepository (class that contains code to retrieve from en write to the database):

```
public async Task<IList<Vakantie>> FindAll()
{
    var query = from v in ParseObject.GetQuery("Vakantie")
                orderby v.Get<string>("titel") ascending
                select v;

    IEnumerable<ParseObject> objects = await query.FindAsync();
    IList<Vakantie> vakanties = new Vakantie[] { };

    foreach (ParseObject vakantieObject in objects)
    {
        Vakantie vakantie = GetVakantie(vakantieObject);
        vakanties.Add(vakantie);
    }

    return vakanties;
}
```

The method `GetVakantie(vakantieObject() is a method I wrote that converts the ParseObject I get from the query result to a Vakantie object from my domain.

When I run this code, I get until the line:

```
IEnumerable<ParseObject> objects = await query.FindAsync();
```

and when Visual Studio actually performs this command, my website just keeps loading and loading. I never get over this line to the next one. It is stuck right there.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. P.S. Please note how I updated your question markup using [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into a classic deadlock scenario that I [describe in full on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In summary, `await` will capture the current "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. Furthermore, the ASP.NET context will only allow one thread at a time. So when a request thread is blocked (on `Task<T>.Result`), the `await` inside of `FindAll` cannot resume the `async` method on that context, and you end up with a deadlock.

To correct it, use async "all the way"; i.e., don't use `Task<T>.Result`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  var vakantiesTask = vakantieRepository.FindAll();
  IEnumerable vakanties = await vakantiesTask;
  return View(vakanties);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that totally worked for me! I have searched all day for a solution, but I'm not really familiar with the whole async await principle. Thanks a lot!